# Why fadeIn doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to fade in from 0.5 opacity to 1.0 opacity. But it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var r = $(".box");r.css({ "opacity":"0.5"});r.text("Box!");r.fadeIn(400);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

But fading out from 0.5 opacity to 0 works:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var r = $(".box");r.css({ "opacity":"0.5"});r.text("Box!");r.fadeOut(400);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Why is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This very much seems like a bug to me; something to do with the fact that you're attempting to `fadeIn` an element which is already visible - `fadeIn` considers an element with opacity of 0.5 to be visible because it checks for the `display` property (in this case it is `block`, not `none`), not for `opacity`. If

`fadeOut` also checks for `display` property. As it is not `none`, `fadeOut` thinks that this element is visible (it doesn't matter what opacity this element has). So `fadeOut` does work in this case.

To achieve the effect you want, try using [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var r = $(".box");r.css({ "opacity":"0.5"});r.text("Box!");r.fadeTo(400,1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: `fadeOut` is "visible => hidden". Since the element is visible, `fadeOut` has no problem.

Comment: So when the element is at 0.5 opacity, fadein thinks that it is already faded in?

Comment: @nicael Almost. All `fadeIn` sees is that the element is **visible**.

Comment: If you let it fade out all the way to zero, it totally screws up.  It alters it's visibility and then when you call fade in, it flickers with 100% opacity momentarily before fading in.  Once again, back an entire decade from where Flash is.  Thanks HTML5.  The simplest stuff is now buggy or impossible, with no cross-browser consistency... with a multi KB library -- otherwise unnecessary -- specifically meant to solve those kinds of problems.  I believe #epicfail is in order.

Answer (score 3):

JQuery's `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` does not change the opacity with numeric values... Instead it uses animation keywords:

Reading the [**uncompressed latest JQuery script**](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js):

```
jQuery.each({
    slideDown: genFx("show"),
    slideUp: genFx("hide"),
    slideToggle: genFx("toggle"),
    fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
    fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" },
    fadeToggle: { opacity: "toggle" }
}
```

It uses the keywords **show** and **hide** in an `animate()` method, which checks for the element's state before applying the effect... Since your element is already visible, the **show** animation will not have an effect...

When using `fadeOut()` however, the **hide** keyword will have an effect since the element is not yet hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It seems fadeIn & fadeOut only work off the display property.  Another option besides fadeTo would be to animate the opacity.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var r = $(".box");r.css({ "opacity":"0.5"});r.text("Box!");r.animate({opacity:1},1000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because your element is already visible so `fadeIn` doesn't serve a purpose. You can set `display: none` in your css to start the element as hidden so that it can fade in.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3mfzg0sL/)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer is incomplete because it lacks an explanation.

Comment: maybe it lacks a little more clarity but i clearly said "your element is already visible"

Comment: In this case this is fading *to* the 0.5. I expect fadein to be the opposite of fadeout.

Answer (score -1):

You should add display: none to your example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        var r = $(".box");r.css({ "opacity":"0.5"});r.text("Box!");r.fadeIn(2500);
    },1000)
})
```

```css
.box {opacity:0;display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```